# Alert is triggered multiple times

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, alert

**The following code works in the following way:**

When I enter incorrect values in the **txtother.textbox** and focuses out, an alert will be displayed as "**Please enter a valid Format Mask."** .
After pressing the "**ok**" button in the Alertbox the **txtOther.focusout** even is triggered again.
i.e. immediately after pressing the **OK** of alert, the same **ALERT** is displayed again.

I have added the code for ur reference:

```
//in mxml File:
<mx:Canvas label="General" >
<mx:VBox>
<mx:Canvas id="cvsGeneral"> 
<mx:TextInput id="txtOther" focusOut="txtOther_Validate();"/>
</mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>                              
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="5%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:HBox width="80%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="left">
<mx:Button width="64" label="Save" id="btnSave" click="btnSave_Click();" focusIn="txtOther_Validate();"/>
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>


//Validating action script is as follows:
public function txtOther_Validate():void{
    var formatMask: String = null;  
        if(txtOther.editable && txtOther.enabled){
            if(txtOther.text != ""){
                formatMask = txtOther.text;
                if(conditions to validate){
                    //some expression
                }               
                if(formatMask.length < 12){
                    Alert.show("Please enter format mask with minimum 12 digits.");
                    txtOther.setFocus();
                    return;
                }               VariableEditControl.getInstance().validateFormatMask(txtOther.text,validateFormatMask_Result,validateFormatMask_Fault, validateFormatMask_Error);
            }
        }   
}
public function validateFormatMask_Result(event:PLEvent): void {
    var result:String = event.getData().toString(); // here lets assume that the result variable is stored as "FAILURE"
    if(result == "FAILURE"){
        Alert.show("Please enter a valid Format Mask.");
        txtOther.setFocus(); //
    }
}
```

I don't want to the alert to come again and again .. 
I need it in such a way that when the ok button of alert is pressed. The `txtother.text` should be in focus, and the alert should not come again and again as before.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing your own custom validation instead of using the validation classes available in flex?

Comment: @J_A_X: Yes actually the requirement was like that.

Comment: I think the Problem is like:
When i press the OK button of the alert box the FocusOut Event of the TxtOther.textbox is triggerd, this is why the alert comes again and again.

Comment: In some sites they suggested me to use callLater() is tat a right option wat do u say? how can i use callLater here in my code?

Comment: Ish, bad requirement/UX.  Anywho, why don't you still use the validation library and listen for the 'invalid' and 'valid' event on the validators.  I believe there's a way to stop them from displaying an errorString.

Comment: using errorString is the very encouraged solution for this problem. But in the requirement they are asking for the ALERT to show error.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have the  `focusIn="txtOther_Validate();"` on the ok button a second time. just remove the focusIn handler and you should be fine.

Comment: @user238284 that i don't understand?!

Comment: i.e. after pressing the **OK** button of the alertBox , the focus should go to the **TxtOther.text** so that the user can directly fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
stage.focus = txtOther;
```

This will works in as3... I don't know about flex.

Comment: ya ur idea is ok. i will test it and mark ur answer as correct.

Comment: but this won't work because he is setting the firstTime variable to true in the eventlistener, so the IF is always called. you would have to move the firstTime out of the eventhandler ... but this is not the solution to the problem, just a workaround.

Comment: ya... my answer is stupid. May be this **stage.focus = txtOther;**

Comment: when using the "stage.focus = txtOther; " multiple number of alerts got created continusly and my system got hanged..

Comment: use the particular container, instead of stage.

Answer (score 0):

I may be in error but I think the alert box won't wait till you close it. So you trigger your validate and immediately set the focus back to the input. Now you click the alert box's ok button which will make the input lose the focus triggering the validation which will raise the alert which will... and so on.