# Focus In /out Problem - button is not focused

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, alert, setfocus

When I press the ***OK** button of the alert box I want the **txtOther.textbox** to be in focus.
Here the txtbox is focused when the alert box is displayed and when I press the OK button of the text box the **txtOther.textbox** is not in focus.

```
MXML SCRIPT:

<mx:Canvas id ="parentCanvas1" label="General" >
<mx:VBox id="parentBox1">
<mx:Canvas id="cvsGeneral"> 
<mx:TextInput id="txtOther" focusOut="txtOther_Validate();"/>
</mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>                              
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Canvas id="parentCanvas2" >
<mx:HBox id="parentBox2" >
<mx:Button label="Save" id="btnSave" click="txtOther_Validate();" />
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>

////////////Action script////////////////////
public function txtOther_Validate(): void {     
     // here lets assume that the result variable is stored as "FAILURE"     
    if(result == "FAILURE"){  
        Alert.show("Please enter a valid Format Mask.");        
         txtOther.setFocus(); //   
         } 
}
```

Here even when the alert box is displayed the focus of the txtother.textbox is also set. But after pressing the OK button of the alert the Focus of the TxtOther.text box is not set. So here I want to trigger the foccus event after pressing the OK button of the alert window and not before. How to do that...

Comment: Which TextInput's focusOut are you performing validation on?  How are you creating your Alert box?  Please show some code.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the question?  Here are instructions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow  If you'd prefer to edit your own question,. look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/how-do-i-edit-my-own-question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006140/alert-is-triggered-multiple-times/7007549#7007549 Actually this is the copy of the above link but here i have made my requirement to simple..
So kindly dont ignore my question

Comment: here even wen the alert box is displayed the focus of the txtother.textbox is also set .. but after pressing the ok button of the alert the Focus of the TxtOther.text box is not set.. so here i wnat to trigger the foccus event after pressing the ok button of the alert window.. how to do that...

Comment: Okay, if it's the same question I voted to close as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instad of normal alert i put the alert like this

```
Alert.show("Please enter a valid Format Mask.", "Validation Error", Alert.OK, this, alrt_close);
```

and then i handle the alert event by

```
private function alrt_close(evt:CloseEvent):void {
    txtOther.setFocus();
```

This worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke Alert.show(), store the returning Alert instance in a variable. On that variable, set up an event listener that will listen to your custom event. The purpose of the handler for that event is to set the focus on txtOther

Here's some code snippets:

```
private var alert:Alert = Alert.show(blah);

alert.addEventListener(mx.events.FlexEvent.REMOVE, removeHandler, false, 0, true);

private function removeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    txtOther.setFocus();
}
```